# Order by group of values

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of locations in a table. The first position begin in '2' and finish in '8', the second position begin in letter 'A' and finish in 'P' . Finally every location has seven elements like this example:

```
SELECT Location FROM WAREHOUSE_LOCATIONS 

Location |
---------|
2A-1     |
2A-2     | 
2A-3     |
2A-4     |
2A-5     |
2A-6     |
2A-7     |
2B-1     |
2B-2     |
2B-3     |
2B-4     |
2B-5     |
2B-6     |
2B-7     |
2C-1     |
...
3A-1     |
...
4A-1     |
...
etc...
```

I want to order this locations like this:

```
Location |
---------|
2A-1     |
2B-1     | 
2C-1     |
2D-1     |
....
2P-1     |
2A-2     |
2B-2     | 
2C-2     |
...
2P-2     |
2A-3     |
2B-3     |
2C-3     |
```

How can i do that?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly you essentially are stuffing 3 data points into a single value. The problem you are facing is because this violates 1NF. That really should be three columns of information. And if needed in that type of format could be a computed column.

Comment: Thanks,  i think you are rigth. I believed that was posible but i have to do this in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(Location, LEN(Location) - CHARINDEX('-', Location)) AS INT),
LEFT(Location, CHARINDEX('-', Location) - 1)
```

Comment: I'd throw in a `CAST` to `INT` on the part after the hyphen, otherwise `'10'` will sort before `'2'`.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote the statement as I was running out the door so it may need a little tweaking. I'm not somewhere I can work on it now. Can you paste the actual error text?

Comment: @Jprada -- that's different from what you show in your example...you don't show 2P-1 or 3A-1.....